# Angular 10 (change) not detected on form inputfield

Tags: angular, forms, text, onchange, input-field

When I use the (change) to detect inputfield changes it only shows me changes when the user leaves the inputfield. this is the html code :

```
<input type="text"  (change)="check('test')" class="form-control form-control-lg" class="form-control" formControlName="title"  [ngClass]="!rForm.controls['title'].valid && rForm.controls['title'].touched ? 'red-border-class' : 'black-border-class'">
```

What am I doing wrong I want to detect a change immediately not after the user goes to the next inputfield.

Someone who can help?

Thx

Comment: Please read up on how change event works on different fields: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Keyup instead of Change may be it would suit your requirement

```
<input type="text"  (keyup)="check('test')" class="form-control form-control-lg" class="form-control" formControlName="title" 
      [ngClass]="!rForm.controls['title'].valid && rForm.controls['title'].touched ? 'red-border-class' : 'black-border-class'">
```

Comment: @Hassan Roshan that work great but what If I use a Datepicker when I click a new date I want to detect the change?

Comment: Angular has (datechange) to do that work you can call the Function in (datechange)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use the (keypress)- or (keyup)-Event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(blur)` event, it will call once you leave  the inputfield

```
<input (blur)='check('test')'/>
```

Comment: I want to detect change before user leaves not after

Answer (score 0):

You have, at least, two ways of doing this.

### Use keyup event

[Better description about keyup](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-the-event-object)

```html
<input (keyup)="check('test')">
```

### valueChanges of FormControl

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges

```js
rForm.controls['title'].valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  check('test');
});
```